# Add or append a div to the Top Left corner of the selection area of imgAreaSelect plugin

Tags: jquery

I am using the imgAreaSelect plugin found at [imgAreaSelect plugin](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/).

The cropping thing is working fine. However, I want to add/append a div to the Top Left corner of the selection area like as shown below:

```
$("#clip-share-1").click(function(){
   $('#pgimg').imgAreaSelect({ x1: 10, y1: 10, x2: 100, y2: 100, handles: true,onSelectEnd: formCanvas });
   $('#someDivId').append('<div class="download-box"><a id="cropDownLoadbtn" class="download-btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a><a href="#" class="btn-close-clip"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</a>\n\
  </div>')
});
```

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this? The default selection container div does not have any id or class defined. I hope you understand my problem.